# How to set a Heroku hosted Twitter bot to run periodically, shutting off the dyno between runs?

Tags: java, heroku, bots, twitter4j

I would like to run my .jar file once every hour or so. Basically, turn the dyno on and let the program run, then turn it off. I am curious if this is possible with a scheduler, and if so, how to implement this method.

I've done Thread.sleep(millis) and just looped around and restarted the programs, but this keeps the dynos on, and you only get 550 free dyno hours which will be used up in less than a month by one bot that is enabled constantly.

Here is the procfile, not sure if it'd be useful.

```
worker: java -jar myapp.jar
```

I assume the correct method is to install a scheduler, but the documentation on this is confusing and insufficient. What would be the simplest way to solve this problem? I have 4 bots I would like to host, and they shouldn't get anywhere near the monthly allowance as long as they're just cutting on every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I could try will be set up free CI/CD e.g, travis-ci, and set to periodical deploy, not pull based or commit based, and make travis-ci pipeline to deploy your app to Heroku periodically ( with out without entire build? ).

And probably you need to change your app to execute only once and then exit?

Another way might be, if you use free tier, if web app runs in free Dynos tier doesn't get any traffic in 30 minutes, it will sleep and those sleep time won't be count as your free time. So I guess you can set travis-ci or something else that runs in every 30+ minutes ( maybe 40 mins to make sure ) and hit your app, and then app runs just once. With this, you'll only use less than 12 hours a day, means you'll still be safe with those 550 free Dynos hours.